# How to create KML file in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

At the moment, my app receives KML file from server and displays all the placemarks in the maps. But there is too much data going back and forth, so now i want to receive only a short string (lat,lang for a few points) from the server.

Is it possible to create KML file on an Android device (any API for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not seem to be any KML libraries that will work well with Android right now.  I have been using the [Simple XML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) library for parsing KML, and is working out well.

However, since you are already receiving the data in a simplified format, you would be much better off using the Google Maps API directly yourself.  This will save the effort of building up the KML, sending it to Google, and then getting back the rendered map.  The tutorial here will help you get started: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Comment: The simplest way to display multiple placemarks from KML is via Intent:                                                          Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=http:/urlOfKML"); 
final Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri1); startActivity(mapIntent);                                      That's why i need to create KML on the device.

Comment: I update my answer with more details.  IMHO, you are better off using the map API directly instead of creating KML.

Comment: You are right, i will have to create overlay items from received coordinates and put them to the map.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [libkml](http://code.google.com/p/libkml/), but it's a native library and you would need the NDK or [gekmllib](http://code.google.com/p/gekmllib/)
which is a Java library you can try to include in your Android project.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CreateKmlFileActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
    private ArrayList<LatLng> latLngArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<LatLng> latLngArrayListLine = new ArrayList<>();
    private Button button, buttonLine;
    private XmlSerializer xmlSerializer;
    private boolean flag = false;
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable runnable;
    GPSTracker gpsTracker;
    private double lat;
    private double lng;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_task3);
        init();
        listener();
    }

    private void init() {
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_find);
        buttonLine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_line);
        supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
        gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);
        lat = gpsTracker.latitude;
        lng = gpsTracker.longitude;
        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gpsTracker.getLocation();
                if (lat != gpsTracker.latitude || lng != gpsTracker.longitude) {
                    latLngArrayListLine.add(new LatLng(gpsTracker.latitude, gpsTracker.longitude));
                    lat = gpsTracker.latitude;
                    lng = gpsTracker.longitude;
                }
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000 * 60);
            }
        };
        if (!gpsTracker.getIsGPSTrackingEnabled()) {
            gpsTracker.showSettingsAlert();
        }
        //gpsTracker.latitude
    }

    private void listener() {
        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                if (!flag)
                    latLngArrayList.add(latLng);
                else
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            }
        });

        buttonLine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                flag = false;
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("testLine.kml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    xmlSerializer = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newSerializer();
                    xmlSerializer.setOutput(fileOutputStream, "UTF-8");
                    xmlSerializer.startDocument(null, null);
                    xmlSerializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "kml");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "Document");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "name");
                    xmlSerializer.text("kmlFile");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "name");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "Style");
                    xmlSerializer.attribute(null, "id", "transGreenPoly");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "LineStyle");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "width");
                    xmlSerializer.text("1");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "width");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "color");
                    xmlSerializer.text("7dff0000");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "color");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "colorMode");
                    xmlSerializer.text("random");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "colorMode");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "LineStyle");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "Style");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "Folder");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "name");
                    xmlSerializer.text("Google Campus");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "name");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "visibility");
                    xmlSerializer.text("1");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "visibility");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "description");
                    xmlSerializer.text("Your Data");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "description");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "Placemark");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "name");
                    xmlSerializer.text("Data");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "name");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "visibility");
                    xmlSerializer.text("1");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "visibility");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "styleUrl");
                    xmlSerializer.text("#transRedPoly");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "styleUrl");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "LineString");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "extrude");
                    xmlSerializer.text("1");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "extrude");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "altitudeMode");
                    xmlSerializer.text("relativeToGround");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "altitudeMode");
                    //xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "outerBoundaryIs");
                    // xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "LinearRing");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "coordinates");
                    for (int i = 0; i < latLngArrayListLine.size(); i++) {
                        if (isPointInPolygon(latLngArrayListLine.get(i), latLngArrayList))
                            xmlSerializer.text(latLngArrayListLine.get(i).longitude + "," + latLngArrayListLine.get(i).latitude + ",17 \n");
                    }
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "coordinates");
                    // xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "LinearRing");
                    //xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "outerBoundaryIs");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "LineString");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "Placemark");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "Folder");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "Document");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "kml");
                    xmlSerializer.endDocument();
                    xmlSerializer.flush();
                    fileOutputStream.close();

                } catch (IOException | XmlPullParserException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });



    }


}
```

Comment: A bunch of code without any explanation is barely an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I know it is too late but [OSMBonusPack](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/) can be used to create kml files.

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.