# Draw a Geographically Accurate Arc on a Map for Android

Tags: java, android, maps, google-maps-android-api-2, mapbox

I would like to draw an arc with a center GPS point and two end GPS points.  I can use any mapping software that can be used with android.

So far I have tried Google Maps for android.  Mapbox for android.  ARCGIS for android.  None of them seem to be able to do this simple task.

I'm guessing I need some-sort of overlay?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey Reafidy, I'd be glad to help you on this issue, What kind of arc are you trying to achieve here? is it a linear line that takes into account the earths spherical shape which end result produces an arc? In any case, arcs can be produces within the Mapbox Android SDK with a little math involved, I'd be glad to show you some methods.

Comment: @cammace - thanks for your help, sorry for the delay I have been away.  Please see my updated question for the table of the shape I am trying to create NZA155.  I can draw the straight lines no problem but the arcs are the issue.

Comment: @Reafidy Are you still looking for an answer on this post?

Comment: Could you post your geodata as text, not image?

Comment: What units are your latitude/longitude? Are they projected or geographic coordinates?

Comment: @Radu - yes definately.

Comment: @antonio - im not sure what you are asking me they are just geographic coordinates.

Comment: @Nikolai.  I will do once im back at my computer.   Away at the moment.

Comment: Geographic coordinates (latitude/longitude) in WGS84 looks like lat=3.659464, long=17.458174, but your coordinates look like 365946.4S, 1745817.4E. What [SRID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRID) are you using? Google Maps API for Android for example only allows WGS84

Comment: why dont you simply use [KML Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/kml#introduction) you already have all coordinates. also you may want to take a look at how to create [kml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628376/how-to-create-kml-file-in-android)

Comment: @UğurB I didnt know that was possible.  Would you care to post a more detailed solution involving kml layer and specifically how to create the kml layer with this particular shape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have to change the geodata representation.

From this:

```
36°46'02.5"S    174°50'03.6"E    GRC
36°56'18.3"S    174°33'09.7"E    CWA    36°52'19.2"S    174°29'23.5"E    5.0'    NM
36°48'19.8"S    174°25'37.7"E    GRC
36°41'06.1"S    174°37'32.9"E    CCA    36°39'54.5"S    174°38'40.7"E    1.5'    NM
36°41'00.3"S    174°39'57.1"E    GRC
36°39'49.4"S    174°41'32.3"E    CCA    36°38'43.5"S    174°40'15.7"E    1.5'    NM
36°39'17.5"S    174°41'59.7"E    GRC
36°39'38.6"S    174°44'37.7"E    GRC
36°37'08.8"S    174°47'27.4"E    CWA    36°42'03.8"S    174°46'17.0"E    5.0'    NM
```

To this:

```
-36.76736    174.83433    GRC
-36.93842    174.55269    CWA    -36.87200    174.48986    0.08333    NM
-36.80550    174.42714    GRC
-36.68503    174.62581    CCA    -36.66514    174.64464    0.02500    NM
-36.68342    174.66586    GRC
-36.66372    174.69231    CCA    -36.64542    174.67103    0.02500    NM
-36.65486    174.69992    GRC
-36.66072    174.74381    GRC
-36.61911    174.79094    CWA    -36.70106    174.77139    0.08333    NM
```

Then you can use them to build a path (e.g., [SVG path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d)):

```
<svg
  ...>
  <g
     transform="matrix(1250,0,0,1250,46206.909,-217995.49)"
     ...>
    <path
       d=" M -36.76736,174.83433 L -36.93842,174.55269 A 0.08333,0.08333 0 0,1 -36.80550,174.42714 L -36.68503,174.62581 A 0.02500,0.02500 0 0,0 -36.68342,174.66586 L -36.66372,174.69231 A 0.02500,0.02500 0 0,0 -36.65486,174.69992 L -36.66072,174.74381 L -36.61911,174.79094 A 0.08333,0.08333 0 0,1 -36.76736,174.83433 Z"
       .../>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[image: SVG example]

Actually, there is no API to create curves, arcs, etc. in GMaps/OSMDroid, so, you should draw them as many small lines. It means doing some math, but this math can be made by [GeographicLib library](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    map.setMultiTouchControls(true);


    IMapController mapController = map.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(9);
    GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(-36.66372, 174.69231);
    mapController.setCenter(startPoint);

    Polygon polyline = new Polygon(this);
    List<GeoPoint> points = new LinkedList<>();

    // I filled the data manually, but it can be done more clever, of course.
    GRC(points, new GeoPoint(-36.76736, 174.83433));
    CWA(points, new GeoPoint(-36.93842, 174.55269),
                new GeoPoint(-36.87200, 174.48986),
                new GeoPoint(-36.80550, 174.42714),
                0.08333);
    CCA(points, new GeoPoint(-36.68503, 174.62581),
                new GeoPoint(-36.66514, 174.64464),
                new GeoPoint(-36.68342, 174.66586),
                0.02500);
    CCA(points, new GeoPoint(-36.66372, 174.69231),
                new GeoPoint(-36.64542, 174.67103),
                new GeoPoint(-36.65486, 174.69992),
                0.02500);
    GRC(points, new GeoPoint(-36.66072, 174.74381));
    CWA(points, new GeoPoint(-36.61911, 174.79094),
                new GeoPoint(-36.70106, 174.77139),
                new GeoPoint(-36.76736, 174.83433), //close shape going to the start point
                0.08333);

    polyline.setPoints(points);
    polyline.setFillColor(0xA0FF00FF);
    polyline.setStrokeColor(Color.BLACK);
    polyline.setStrokeWidth(2f);
    map.getOverlays().add(polyline);
    map.invalidate();
}

private void CCA(List<GeoPoint> points, GeoPoint startPoint, GeoPoint centerPoint, GeoPoint endPoint, double radius) {
    points.add(startPoint);

    GeodesicData f = Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse(centerPoint.getLatitude(), centerPoint.getLongitude(), startPoint.getLatitude(), startPoint.getLongitude());
    GeodesicData t = Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse(centerPoint.getLatitude(), centerPoint.getLongitude(), endPoint.getLatitude(), endPoint.getLongitude());

    double ffaz = f.azi1;
    double tfaz = t.azi1;

    final int decrement = 1;
    while (Math.abs((int)ffaz) != Math.abs((int)tfaz)) {
        GeodesicData llb = Geodesic.WGS84.Direct(centerPoint.getLatitude(), centerPoint.getLongitude(), ffaz,  f.s12);
        points.add(new GeoPoint(llb.lat2, llb.lon2));
        ffaz -= decrement;
        if (ffaz <0) {
            ffaz += 360;
        }
    }

    points.add(endPoint);
}

private void CWA(List<GeoPoint> points, GeoPoint startPoint, GeoPoint centerPoint, GeoPoint endPoint, double radius) {
    points.add(startPoint);

    GeodesicData f = Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse(centerPoint.getLatitude(), centerPoint.getLongitude(), startPoint.getLatitude(), startPoint.getLongitude());
    GeodesicData t = Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse(centerPoint.getLatitude(), centerPoint.getLongitude(), endPoint.getLatitude(), endPoint.getLongitude());

    double ffaz = f.azi1;
    double tfaz = t.azi1 > 0 ? t.azi1 : 360 + t.azi1;

    final int increment = 1;
    while (Math.abs((int)ffaz) != Math.abs((int)tfaz)) {
        GeodesicData llb = Geodesic.WGS84.Direct(centerPoint.getLatitude(), centerPoint.getLongitude(), ffaz, f.s12);
        points.add(new GeoPoint(llb.lat2, llb.lon2));
        ffaz += increment;
        if (ffaz>360) {
            ffaz -= 360;
        }
    }

    points.add(endPoint);
}

private void GRC(List<GeoPoint> points, GeoPoint geoPoint) {
    points.add(geoPoint);
}
```

I used osmdroid+OSMBonusPack, but the code is quite universal and can be used with Google Maps easily.

[The full source code](https://github.com/lassana/osmdroid-shape-extension/).

Result:

[image: osmdroid and OSMBonusPack together]

Also, would you mind telling what kind of geodata you posted? The shape on the map looks like an allowed flight zone, I guess.

Comment: This is excellent.  I will take a good look over this and get back to you.

Comment: Correct it is airspace and i will need to draw many of these shapes.

Comment: is this method suitable for creating many of these shapes and displaying them as you have above?  There are around 46 of them, most are not as complicated as this shape.  Or will it slow the app to much?

Comment: I guess that you can create many of these shape, but perhaps you will should move the points building code to an another background thread. Also, if some of your shapes will contain too many points, you can reduce that quantity using the [Douglas-Peucker algorithm](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/blob/0310258c53244a485fda0ff0dd7829e5557b531b/OSMBonusPack/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/utils/DouglasPeuckerReducer.java).

Comment: there appears to a bug with some shapes.  I have added the raw data to my original question and a screenshot of how it should look.  Are you able to assist?  I just don't understand the math enough to debug it myself.

Comment: I think I fixed it: https://github.com/lassana/osmdroid-shape-extention/commit/e466119e88c41733a744625d8ec0dbba881368f6 Are there more problematic shapes?

Comment: Yes that fixed that one but there are a couple more shapes not drawing correctly see my edited question once again (excuse the free hand MS paint image).  Thanks - I really appreciate your help.

Comment: D'oh, I see. I'll try to fix it. Perhaps there are some mistakes in calculating azimuth (CCA&CWA methods). Also, could you post "radius" values?

Comment: Okay, now I can draw that shape, but the fix breaks an existing code and I'm still looking the universal solution: https://i.imgur.com/j05w1Zk.png

Comment: Please see [this branch](https://github.com/lassana/osmdroid-shape-extention/tree/issue_1)

Comment: I'm sure we must be getting close, the shapes look awesome and its really starting to look cool.  See my edit for another problematic shape.  Thanks again, appreciate your help.

Comment: Actually I think I found the solution I used:  `double ffaz =   (f.azi1 < 0) ?  360 + f.azi1: f.azi1;
        double tfaz =   (t.azi1 < 0) ?  360 + t.azi1: t.azi1;`

Comment: Well, I think you're right. https://github.com/lassana/osmdroid-shape-extention/blob/master/device-2016-03-31-124717.png

Comment: Sorry to ask, but any chance you could help me with another problem,  you seem to be an expert in this field...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36439031/determine-if-polygon-is-within-bounds

Comment: Ok, I will try to find an anwer

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, I can't really give you a complete answer right now as this question requires heavy math and I'm unable to fully understand the data you have shown in the table. I assume you are trying to have an end result that looks something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example_arc.html). If that is the case, you have a center point, radius, and the arc starting LatLng and end LatLng (This could also be calculated from the center point with additional math). I'll try and update this answer if I get a chance to write some code handling the math side. As far as I know, none of the map libraries (Google Maps, Mapbox) include this.

Basically, I'd write a method that returns a bunch of latlng points following the arc you wish to draw. From this, i'd draw a line using the `addPolyline` method.

```
// Draw line from list of LatLng called pointsArray
mapView.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
        .add(pointsArray)
        .color(Color.parseColor("#3bb2d0"))
        .width(2));
```

Hopefully this helps you out, at least with getting started and like I said, I'll try and add the math bits later on if I get a chance.

Comment: Hi, please check my updated question - hopefully the image helps.  I am trying to draw the blue line shape marked by the two black arrows on a map of new zealand.  This can be derived from the table, I have labeled numbers 1-9 from the table on the image to show how the shape is derived.

Comment: Wow that is an extremely complex shape. I'd still tackle this problem the same way given above. Calculate a bunch of points that follow the shapes perimeter and then draw a polyline or possibly a polygon since it's an enclosed shape. The only parts that are tricky are the arcs and like mentioned above in my answer, to my knowledge, none of the mapping libraries make this easy.