# Determine if Polygon is Within Map Bounds

Tags: java, android, geometry, google-maps-android-api-2, polygon

I have a big list of polygons (consisting of google maps polygon options) which I would like to check if they are within the bounds of the screen before drawing them.

How do I determine if the polygon is within the screen bounds.

Something like this:

```
   List<PolygonOptions> polygons = getPolygons();

    LatLngBounds bounds = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;

    for (int l = 1; l <= polygons.size(); l++) {
        if (bounds.Contains(polygons.get(l))) {
            map.addPolygon(polygons.get(l));
        }
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding all shapes in e.g. `onCreate` method? Are there some performance issues in that case?

Comment: @Nikolai, I have done yes, however once I add them to the OSMDroid map it freezes for around 2 seconds whilst panning.   Google maps does not have this issue, I'm guessing the drawing engine must be different,  once the polygons are drawn you can pan no problem without freezing.  However I need to remove and add some shapes at different zoom levels for clarity.  As there are so many shapes, when doing this it freezes for 2-3 seconds.  So I would like to just show the polygons and way points for the screen to cut down on the work required.    THanks so much for taking a look.

Comment: I also tried the Douglas-Peucker algorithm but it made little difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you don't need to check if each point from polygon are  visible - you should do it for only four points that can be easily calculated:

[image]

And every time when the user moves the map you should put on the map polygons whose rectangular border is inside visible bounds; something like this:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;
    map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
            showPolygons();
        }
    });
    showPolygons();
}

private void showPolygons() {
    if (map == null) return;
    final LatLngBounds bounds = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
    for (PolygonOptionsWrapper wrapper : wrappers) {
        if (wrapper.within(bounds)) {
            if (!wrapper.isAdded()) {
                wrapper.addTo(map);
            }
        } else {
            if (wrapper.isAdded()) {
                wrapper.removeFrom(map);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[The full source code](https://gitlab.com/lassana/googlemaps-shapes/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/gitlab/lassana/myapplication).

[image]

Comment: Thanks,  your a legend. Can it be modified so that even if only a section of the polygon is on the map it is still drawn?  Currently if a small part of it moves off the map the polygon is removed and I don't want a user to think there is no airspace there.

Comment: So if any of the points 1,2,3,4 you have shown in your diagram above are on the screen then show the polygon.

Comment: @Reafidy please have a look at [this commit](https://gitlab.com/lassana/googlemaps-shapes/commit/946cbb0f11afcb88723c1388953b1523302e31e7)

Comment: That is much better, one small problem if the screen size is inside the shape, but the shape's sides still pass through the screen then the shape should be displayed. I have added a couple of images to my original post to show the problem.  Additionally:  I doubt it will matter if we end up drawing a few extra shapes where the screen is inside the shape but the shapes sides don't cross the screen.  Otherwise I am guessing the math would get two complicated.

Comment: Just one another statement: [b6cd7c0f](https://gitlab.com/lassana/googlemaps-shapes/commit/b6cd7c0f2cb64549efb74b25742c176998286717).

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much.  I could not have done that on my own!

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for some similar solution - what I found could be helpfull for somebody.
Basicly the best aproach is to use buildin methods

1. For points - use [**containsLocation**()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation)
2. For poly/bounds (as in your case) - use **[intersects](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngBounds.intersects)** - method from google.maps.LatLngBounds class

example:

```
if (currentViewport.intersects(bounds)) {    
//do stuff  
}
```